# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: jquery

Не получается запустить функцию контракта.
Использую **web3.js** и **jquery-3.2.1.min.js**

Функция на **pragma solidity**:

```
function checkSertificate(address CoopAdress/ address member) constant returns (uint) {
    constant returns (uint) {
        require (member != 0x0);
        require (Coops[CoopAddess]);

        StandardSertificate s = StandardSertificate(CoopAddess);
        return s.issued(member);
    }
```

код в файле **JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let val = contractInstance.checkSertificate.call().uint256();

    $("#checkSertificateContainer").html(val);
});
```

Понимаю, что `at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs`

Однако не знаю что надо прописать в коде, чтобы эта функция запустилась с результатом.

Comment: какая версия web3?

Comment: Версию не знаю, но пользуюсь вот этой https://cdn.rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит, что не переданы аргументы, поэтому нужно при вызове передать эти параметры.

```
let val = contractInstance.checkSertificate(adreess1, address2);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79769/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-invalid-number-of-arguments-to-solidity-function).